# Can you log to a 3rd party service from Grails 2 app?

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j

I have configured and started using the built in log4j package in my grails 2.5.4 app. I want to be able to send these logs to a 3rd party service through TCP or something similar. The only appenders in the documentation though are a database, console, or a file. Is there a way to set up a TCP appender or send the info to a .groovy file so I can send the log through a request?

Any info or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up a TCP appender or send the info to a .groovy
> file so I can send the log through a request?

Yes.  You have a number of options.  One is to use [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html).  Another is you could write our own appender that does whatever you want.